# Converting Redis output string to bit string

Tags: string, redis, hex

```
127.0.0.1:6379> setbit mykey 1 1
(integer) 0
127.0.0.1:6379> setbit mykey 23 1
(integer) 0
127.0.0.1:6379> setbit mykey 345 1
(integer) 0
127.0.0.1:6379> get mykey
"@\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@"
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

I want to parse the above output string ( as a string of bits, like "100000000011...") to get the indexes of the set bits, how would I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You know the `setbit` is just set the bit of a string, so the `mykey` is holding a string. when you use the command `get mykey`, it just return the string value.

And the `\x00` is a also a char, you could refer this [ASCII TAble](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Every char has eight bits, and the bitmap is just composed of all bits of every char of the string. **its order is that every 8 bits's order is char's order in string, and in this every 8 bits, the order of bit is from the high bit to low bit**. for example, if the string is `@\x00`, then the length of string is 2, the bits length is 16. The ascii value of `@` is 64 in decimal, and the ascii of `\x00` is 0.

So its bitmap is :

```
0100 0000 0000 0000
```

So their offsets is from 0 to 15 from the left to right.

If you have a doubt about this, you could execute this commands in redis-cli to test:

```
setbit test 1 1
setbit test 15 0
get test
```

It will be `@\x00`.

So the relation between the bitmap and string is clear, we could use the string to get the bitmap we want.

just use a simple python script:

```
s = "@\x00"
bitmap = ""
for c in s:
    x = ord(c)
    str = bin(x).split('b')[1]
    if len(str) < 8 : 
       str = '0' * (8-len(str)) + str
    bitmap += str
print bitmap
```

In this script , it uses the `ord` to get ascii value of char, and use to bin to convert the dec to bin, and add 0 to high bit it length is smaller than 8

the output is :

```
0100000000000000
```

Comment: Nice answer - I would only add that the sample script is (?) Pythonic and clarify that @ and x00 are not the same character